# UISearchController hides tableView when query is empty

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

Somehow, when my search string is empty, even though my data array still holds information and `numberOfRowsInSection` / `numberOfSections` still return the according information, the tableView is hidden.
I put this code into my `UISearchResultsUpdating` (searchResultsUpdater):

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    print(tableView.isHidden)
    // my program logic to fetch data with that string from server
    // and reload the tableView
}
```

and it clearly states that the `isHidden` property is set to `true` as soon as I delete all the text in the search bar.
For now, in that exact spot where you can see the `print()`, I put `tableView.isHidden = false` but there should be a better method, something like `hideTableViewWhenSearchEmpty` or along those lines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide more code on how you create your `UISearchController`?

Comment: How about using [UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbardelegate) and `tableView.isHidden = TRUE  IF SEARCHBARTEXT IS EMPTY`